# Where does MonoMac.dll reside in OSX?

Tags: monomac

I'm trying to document the original source for MonoMac.dll. I do realize that it shows up in the bin directory when I compile a MonoMac project, but where is the original? Finder doesn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shipped as an addin to Xamarin Studio. Look in `/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.MonoMac`.

(You can explore the Xamarin Studio bundle by right-clicking on the .app, and choosing 'Show Package Contents')

Comment: This location seems to have changed now. Any idea where it is now?

Comment: It looks like they moved it to "Resources". Something like this: Xamarin Studio ▸ Contents ▸ Resources ▸ lib ▸ monodevelop ▸ AddIns ▸ MonoDevelop.MonoMac